# D3 line graph issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have d3 line graph that is constantly updated with new set of data. The issue is my line graph is drawn above the some rectangular blocks. On page load my line graph is always in the front of the rect but after the page is being refreshed the line graph is going behind the rectangular block. Can any of you help me fix this problem ?

My code is set up like this

```
function drawRect(SVG, cData, type) {
            let selector = '.ca';
            let className = 'c a';
            let tcHeight = verticalSize + MIN_CELL_PADDING;
            let getTranslateString = function (index) {
            let yVal = columnHeight - ((index + 1) * tcHeight);
            return `translate(${xVal}, ${yVal})`;
            let rects = d3.select(columnSVG)
                .selectAll(selector)
                .data(cData.filter((d) => {
                    return d;
                }));
            rects.enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', className)
                .attr('transform', (d, ix) => {
                return getTranslateString(ix);
                })
                .each(function () {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .append('rect')
                        .attr('width', cellSize)
                        .attr('height', verticalSize)
                        .attr('rx', 4)
                        .attr('ry', 4)
                        .attr('time', (d) => {
                            return cData.date;
                        })
                        .attr('fill', (d) => {
                            return changeColor(d);
                        });
                });

            rects.transition()
                .attr('transform', (d, ix) => {
                    return getTranslateString(ix);
                });

            rects.each(function (d) {
                let node = d3.select(this);
                node.selectAll('rects').transition()
                    .attr('width', cellSize)
                    .attr('height', verticalSize)
                    .attr('rx', 4)
                    .attr('ry', 4)
        }

    function drawOline(aData, dData, time) {
                let aLine = d3.svg.line()
                    .defined((d) => {
                        return !isNaN(d.Ptile);
                    })
                    .x((d) => {
                        return ptime(moment(d.day).utc());
                    })
                    .y((d) => {
                        return aY(d.Ptile);
                    });

                let dLine = d3.svg.line()
                    .defined((d) => {
                        return !isNaN(d.Ptile);
                    })
                    .x((d) => {
                        return ptime(moment(d.day).utc());
                    })
                    .y((d) => {
                        return dY(d.Ptile);
                    });

                if (aData && aData.length > 0) {
                    if (g.select('.aline')[0][0] == null) {
                        g.append('g')
                            .append('path')
                            .datum(aData)
                            .attr('class', 'line aline')
                            .attr('fill-opacity', 1.0)
                            .attr('d', aline);
                    } else {
                        g.select('.aline')
                            .datum(aData)
                            .transition()
                            .attr('fill-opacity', 1.0)
                            .attr('d', aline);
                    }
                } else {
                    g.select('.aline')
                        .transition()
                        .attr('fill-opacity', 1.0)
                        .attr('d', aline);
                }

                if (dData && dData.length > 0) {
                    if (g.select('.dline')[0][0] == null) {
                        g.append('g')
                            .append('path')
                            .datum(dData)
                            .attr('class', 'line dline')
                            .attr('fill-opacity', 1.0)
                            .attr('d', dline);
                    } else {
                        g.select('.dline')
                            .datum(dData)
                            .transition()
                            .attr('fill-opacity', 1.0)
                            .attr('d', dline);
                    }
                } else {
                    g.select('.dline')
                        .transition()
                        .attr('fill-opacity', 1.0)
                        .attr('d', dline);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You will have to provide more code than that.

Answer (score 2):

The visual occlusion (hiding) of some SVG objects by others (e.g. lines by rects, or vice versa) is very dependent on their drawing order. Unlike HTML/CSS, SVG does not have a true `z-index` or "what's on top?" indicator.

The trick is often to draw the items you want to see on top last. That's not always convenient, however. For example, you may not way to redraw lines every time you redraw the blocks.

A way to preserve the visual ordering of objects, even when they're redrawn, is to put them into `<g>` groups. The ordering of the groups need not change, even if the items are updated. For example:

```
var rectsG = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'rects');
var linesG = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'lines');
```

Then instead of drawing into the global `svg` element, direct your appends to individual groups. They will act as layers:

```
linesG.append('line')
      ...more here...
rectsG.append('rect')
      ...more here...
```

Because the groups are ordered in the document top to bottom, it really doesn't matter what order you draw or redraw their constituent elements. The ordering of the `<g>` containers is what will determine visual occlusion.

Comment: Thank you @jonathon. I will try the <g> ordering

Comment: Hello Jonathon, I have used <g> ordering but still it did not work. I have provided more code. Can you please help me what else is wrong in my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user6860877 I will look at the code in more detail, but I can immediately see multiple errors. You cannot append `rects`, for example. The attributes `rx` and `ry` don't do what you think they do. There is no attribute `time`. Et cetera. Don't conclude that the reason it's doesn't work is a failure of the `<g>` layering trick. There are many causes here.

Comment: At least fix `rect` to not read `rects`. `rx` and `ry` work if you're trying to round your rectangles and use a transform to move them into place. Can't evaluate that translate as you don't provide `getTranslateString`. What you're trying to do with the (not legit SVG) `time` attr and the low-level unwrapping of D3 selections, I can't say. There's much right here, but layering is just one of the problems. You've built up a complex unworking system, and are now trying to debug "beyond your pay grade." Google Gall's Law.